Excel Power BI Dataset Refresh Error: COM error: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Azureclient
I have an issue with refreshing my Excel file, which is connected to a Power BI dataset. When I click "Refresh" in Excel, I get the following error message:

COM error: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Azureclient, an error occurred while sending the request.

This issue started recently, and I haven’t made any changes to the connection or the dataset itself. I have tried:

Restarting Excel
Checking my internet connection
Making sure my Power BI dataset is accessible directly through the Power BI service
Re-signing into my Power BI account within Excel
None of these steps have resolved the issue. Does anyone have any suggestions on what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Additional Info:
Excel version: 2402
Thank you in advance for your help!
